# text inline with an horizontal rull

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image

I am trying to type a title on the near to a two horizontal line
I use Bootstrap classes, like:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4"><p><!-- title hear --></p></div>
   <div class="col-md-8"><p><hr /><hr /></p></div>
</div>
```

is there any other method?

Example:

[image]

Comment: Can you draw what you want on Paint or something like that ?

Comment: got to edition.cnn.com search for the word _Featured sections_, you will two rules on the near to the title, I am serching on the net, I have to use in the css, for example: `h2:before` ..

Comment: I will put the answer in a while

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/aWloy this is the example i am trying to draw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

h1 {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin: 0 0 -10px 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.line {
  flex: 2 0 0;
  border-bottom: 3px double #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h1>
    Hello
  </h1>
  <div class="line">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it is something like this, but i want the title in the left, on his right two horizontal rule to the end of the page

Comment: A quest. What is the function of `flex` ??

Comment: and here i use for inline heading and line div.